# I'm trying to run a Python script that will use the Summarize Elevation built-in tool but am getting errors

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am trying to automate a process for generating slope and aspect by using the built-in Summerize Elevation tool in ArcGIS Pro. My code is as follows:

```
import arcpy


Elevation_Path = r"C:\\Users\\me\\stuff\\Geodatabase.gdb"
TESTING = Elevation_Path + "\\TESTING"
  

# Ensure paths are valid
print ("Confirming file paths")
feature_list = [TESTING]
for feature in feature_list:
    if not arcpy.Exists(feature):
        print('Could not find: {0}! Exiting...'.format(feature))
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('...Found datasets: {0}'.format(feature))


test = arcpy.agolservices.SummarizeElevation(TESTING, DEMResolution="FINEST", IncludeSlopeAspect="SLOPE_ASPECT")[0]
```

I am getting the following error:

File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 1101, in **getitem**
if key >= self.outputCount:
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects_base.py", line 90, in _get
return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(getattr(self._arc_object, attr_name))
RuntimeError: ResultObject: Error in getting the number of returned outputs

Comment: [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) is a good way of combining paths.

Comment: Are you getting this error at the very last line or later on once you use `test`?

Comment: Would you mind mention the code where your use summarize elevation ?